# OData filter on array property to return empty array or array

Tags: json, odata

I have a JSON object similar to this one:

```
{
  "customers": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "bob",
      "orders": [{"id": 1, "customerId": 1, "itemId": 6}]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "jane",
      "orders": [{"id": 2, "customerId": 2, "itemId": 7}]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to query it like....

```
...odata/customers?$expand=orders&$filter=orders/any(order: order/itemId eq 6)
```

...and get...

```
{
  "customers": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "bob",
      "orders": [{"id": 1, "customerId": 1, "itemId": 6}]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "jane",
      "orders": []
    }
  ]
}
```

but what I get is...

```
{
  "customers": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "bob",
      "orders": [{"id": 1, "customerId": 1, "itemId": 6}]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get all the customers and I only want the filter to apply to the "orders".

What can I do to get this result?

Answer (score 0):

Just got the same problem!
Solved by filtering my expand by the same condition in any().

```
applications?$expand=accounts($filter=idUser eq 5)&$filter=accounts/any(account: account/idUser eq 5)
```

Maybe to late but hope it will help someone else ;)